# NodeJS not found after installing

Tags: nodejs

I have this program which needs nodejs to work. So when I install nodejs and test it out, it doesn't work. This is exactly what I did:

```
    multiplemark@multiplemark-OptiPlex-GX280:~$ sudo -s
    [sudo] password for multiplemark: 
    root@multiplemark-OptiPlex-GX280:~# apt-get install nodejs && npm
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      libmaven-clean-plugin-java libplexus-compiler-manager-java
      libmaven-filtering-java libmaven-shared-io-java libax25
      libmaven-jar-plugin-java libmaven-install-plugin-java
      libplexus-compiler-api-java libmaven-file-management-java
      libplexus-compiler-java libmaven-archiver-java
      libmaven-resources-plugin-java libc-ares-dev node-node-uuid libssl-dev
      libssl-doc libmaven-dependency-tree-java openbsd-inetd zlib1g-dev
      libplexus-compiler-javac-java libv8-dev libmaven-shade-plugin-java libev-dev
      libplexus-digest-java libmaven-compiler-plugin-java
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      nodejs
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/680 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 2,473 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
    (Reading database ... 186254 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking nodejs (from .../nodejs_0.6.12~dfsg1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for doc-base ...
    Processing 1 added doc-base file...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Setting up nodejs (0.6.12~dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/node to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode.

    root@multiplemark-OptiPlex-GX280:~# nodejs
    No command 'nodejs' found, did you mean:
     Command 'nodefs' from package 'noweb' (main)
    nodejs: command not found
    root@multiplemark-OptiPlex-GX280:~#
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to launch nodejs is `node`